# How to make MultipartFilter to work with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, multipart

As the reference, we have two options to make Multipart works with Spring Security:

- Placing MultipartFilter before Spring Security
- Include CSRF token in action

For the first option, I've try these things:

- Create SecurityApplicationInitializer class:

> ```
> public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
>     @Override
>     protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
>         insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
>     }
> }
> ```

- Change spring security filter order in application.properties `spring.security.filter.order=5`
- And then add FilterRegistrationBean

> ```
> @Bean
> @Order(0)
>     public FilterRegistrationBean registerMultipartFilter() {
>     FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new MultipartFilter());
>     reg.setOrder(1);
>     return reg;
> }
> ```

Unfortunately, none of them work, I tried to disable csrf protection and it works as intended, so what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: I tried them one by one, and then tried all of them at the same time. I've tried to remove the @EnableWebSecurity too but It still doesn't work

Comment: For the second option (add CSRF token into the form), it works perfectly

Comment: yeah, by using second option, but I really want to know why the first option doesn't work

Comment: thanks bro, sorry for over-complicated the problem, it turns out what I need to do is add a `th:action` into the form

Answer (score 3):

It turns out Spring Boot already do a lot of things for us. The problem is not MultipartFilter at all. We don't even need to set up MultipartFilter for CSRF Protection when using Spring Boot.

The real problem is my Thymeleaf form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
```

Without `th:action`, spring boot won't automatically insert a hidden csrf token for us.

```
<form th:action="''" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

[image]